# Create a polymer element using an ES6 class?

Tags: class, ecmascript-6, polymer-1.0

I'd like to be able to create a class to pass to the Polymer function to create elements. The obvious use case is to have a base class that our developers can use to build Polymer elements.

However, Polymer seems to ignore lifecycle methods on the class. The following code does not run #created. Is there a workaround?

```
//attempt 1
class CustomElement {

  is = 'sample-multi-view-polymer-buic'

  created() { console.log('created') } // never called
}

export default Polymer(new CustomElement()) // doesn't work (see error below)
```

Since I'm using Babel to transpile ES6 to ES5, the above is equivalent to the code below. It also does not work.

```
 // attempt2
function CustomElement() {

  this.is = 'sample-multi-view-polymer-buic'
}

CustomElement.prototype.created= function() { console.log('hi') } //never called
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an [article for using ES6 with Polymer in the docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/articles/es6.html)

---

So there's 2 things missing on your end:

- You are missing a `beforeRegistered()` method.
- You need to use `Polymer()` to instantiate your element's Class.

Here's how I do it:

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
<link href="paper-input/paper-input.html" rel="import">

<dom-module id="x-example">

  <template>
    <paper-input value="{{name::input}}"></paper-input>
    <h4>{{name}}</h4>
  </template>
  
  <script>
    "use strict";

    class xExample {

      beforeRegister() {
        this.is = "x-example";
        this.properties = {
          name: {
            type: String,
            value: "I'm a data-binded prop"
          }
        }
      }

      ready() {
        console.log("ready");
      }
    }

    Polymer(xExample);
  </script>

</dom-module>

<x-example></x-example>
```

**Note:**

- The above snippet only works on Chrome/FF
- For everything else you can of course "babelize" it.

Comment: Yea I eventually found this article. There is one important gotcha---you cannot define any properties on the class. You must define them on the "this" object in #beforeRegister... This was very confusing.

Comment: Same here but I quickly got the hang of it

Comment: Yea well I'm writing a framework using Polymer... that means a learning curve for other developers (and wierd bugs). Will have to write a helper to validate Polymer classes.